# 2 groups loose their permissions in lists

Tags: 2010, permissions, groups

I have 2 SharePoint 2010 groups.

In several lists they have manually configured permissions.
Other groups have the same permission setting on the same lists.

Some times these and only these 2 groups lose the permissions on these lists.

The groups still exist in site collections. They are not being deleted.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you have latest updates installed? Somewhere beginning of this year an update was released that fixed this issue.

Comment: I have June 2014 CU on my server.

Comment: Are these groups associated as Owners/Members/Visitors, etc.? Is this periodical or triggered by an unknown event? Have you tried enabling security audit on the site collection to gain better understanding of what's going on?

Comment: No, they are ordinary groups. The problem is not periodical and it looks like there is some unknown event that connected with problem. I have completely forgotten about security audit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Auditing for the list in questions and review the audit logs after the event occurs to see if there are any explicit action taking place.  It should record the account used to remove the groups. This will hopefully at least get you a time stamp of when it occurs.

With time in hand - check your timer jobs and any scheduled tasks across the servers.  If you have any 3rd party management tools like ControlPoint or DocAve - check their governance configurations (depending on how they are configured they will reset permissions).